# Does JDBC template cache connection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have an java-spring web application, which will read, write and delete information from a user upload SQLite DB. I am using JDBCtemplate to set connection, query the DB and update the information.

I observed one behavior during my tests:

Every time,after users uploaded a new SQLite db file(it will has the same name, place at the same directory as the old DB file), if they do not reboot/restart tomcat, jdbcquery will report the db was corrupted exception.

To me this looked like the JDBCtemplate somehow cached the connection and is trying to resume the connection with the old db?

If so, do you know anyway to refresh the connection without rebooting the application?

```
final SingleConnectionDataSource dataSource = new singleConnectionDataSource();
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new applicationException(MessageTemplateNames.GENERAL_UNKNOWN_ERROR, e);
}

createDirectoryForDbIfNotExists();
dataSource.setUrl(String.format("%s%s", JDBC.PREFIX, getDbFileLocation()));
dataSource.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Comment: I don't think you can just replace the SQLite db file from under an open DataSource. You want to close the old DataSource before replacing the file, then create a new DataSource (and make sure no code still uses the old one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JDBCTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#JdbcTemplate-javax.sql.DataSource-) does not handle connection.It obtains the connection from the datasource set to it.

From the reference documentation for [SingleConnectionDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/SingleConnectionDataSource.html)

> Implementation of SmartDataSource that wraps a single JDBC Connection
>   which is not closed after use.  .....
>
> This is primarily intended for testing. For example, it enables easy
>   testing outside an application server, for code that expects to work
>   on a DataSource. In contrast to DriverManagerDataSource, **it reuses the
>   same Connection all the time**, avoiding excessive creation of physical
>   Connections.

A [DriverManagerDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) will suite your requirement to get a new connection without reboot

> Simple implementation of the standard JDBC DataSource interface,
>   configuring the plain old JDBC DriverManager via bean properties, and
>   r**eturning a new Connection from every getConnection call.**

**Update**

My answer might not solve your original problem , but will only answer the question for new connection without reboot. Please go through @Thilo's comment on the same.

Comment: I think creating a new connection every time *might* actually solve the original problem as well, depending on how SQLite internally implements these connections, not sure. But if performance is a concern, some kind of caching would be beneficial.